# Inside JavaScript Code call html page without iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call the html pages inside JavaScript code and assign the page into a variable without iframe.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to solve this problem with the $.get method.

```
var externalHtml;
$.get('external_page.html', function(data){
    externalHtml = data;
});
```